# Need suggestion on Silverlight application

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight-4.0

I am a beginner in silver light. I created a test application, in which on top there are menus like Home, About Us etc?? and there is a grid control to show content related to menu.

I created controls for Home, About Us etc, and I add this control on a click of associated menu. but I am looking for some generic way, rather than handling click of each menu separately, I also created a common click event, but the problem how can I get the Home COntrol or a About Us Control to add in a grid. In click event method I can get the clicked menu Information. I can write switch statement but it will also not called as a generic.

Something Like find a particular page/Control by its name in a whole silverlight application and add it to my grid.

Thanx!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Ria Services and MEF. I'm currently on a Silverlight project and we are relying heavily on Ria Services and MEF. We are using a VMMV approach. It's working out nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Silverlight has the Frame and Page controls to help you with some of these issues.

Check out:
  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838245%28v=vs.95%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This could be solved by using silverlight [navigation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838245%28v=VS.95%29.aspx), have a look at this [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dphill/archive/2008/10/07/silverlight-navigation-part-1.aspx) and [here](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Silverlight-3-Navigation-API.aspx)

you can then do something like:

```
this.MainFrame.Navigate(new Uri("Page2.Xaml",UriKind.Relative)); 
// where page 2 is your page name taken from your menu item
```